# Perl regex get word between a pattern

Tags: shell-script, regular-expression, perl

I have a working perl regex using grep. I am trying to understand how it  works.

Here is the command command.

```
grep -oP '(?<=location>)[^<]+' testFile1.xml
```

Here are the contents of `testFile1.xml`

```
<con:location>C:/test/file1.txt</con:location></con:dataFile>/con:dataFiles></con:groupFile>
```

And this is the result

```
C:/test/file1.txt
```

I am trying to understand the regex, i.e. this part `(?<=location>)[^<]+`

Comment: See http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(?<=...)` is a *look-behind* PCRE operator. By itself, it doesn't match anything but acts as a condition (that what's on the left matches `...`).

`(?<=X)Y` matches `Y` provided that what's on the left matches `X`. In `blahYfooXYbar`, that matches the second `Y`, the `X` is not part of what is being matched. The `(?<=X)` itself matches the zero-width (*imaginary*) spot just before that `Y`. Here illustrated:

```
$ echo X-RAY THE FOX | perl -lpe 's/(?<=X)/<there>/g'
X<there>-RAY THE FOX<there>
```

Because with `-o`, `grep` only prints the *matched* portion, that's a way to make it print what's *after* the `location>` (here what matches `[^>]+`: one or more (`+`) non-`<` characters (`[^>]`) so everything up to (but not included) the next `<` character or the end of the line provided it's not empty).

Another approach is to use `\K` (in newer versions of PCRE) to reset the start of the matched portion:

```
grep -Po 'location>\K[^>]+'
```

Note that `-P` and `-o` are GNU extensions. With recent versions (8.11 or over) of `pcregrep` (another `grep` implementation that uses PCRE), you can also do:

```
pcregrep -o1 'location>([^>]+)'
```

(`-o1` prints what's captured by the 1<sup>st</sup> (here unique) `(...)`)

Comment: I under stand the look-behind part. I am still not sure what does "[^<]+" mean? does it mean anything starts with "<" symbol?

Comment: also I tried the `pcregrep` and it's says "pcregrep: Unknown option letter '1' in "-o1"

Comment: @Sas, See if my latest edit make it clearer.

Comment: @Sas, `-o<n>` was added in 8.11 (Dec 2010). You probably have an older version. (I do mention _recent versions_ in my answer though I hadn't realised it was almost 6 years ago it was added. Time flies...).

Comment: @Sas If you don't understand basics like `[^abc]`, then I recommend reading through [the docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) once or twice. Especially for PCRE, this is time well spent, as almost every programming language that implements regexes will use syntax & semantics similar to this. (But, keep in mind that POSIX/shell regexes are fairly different; those are the two most common variants one needs to use.)